# Tensorflow Serving on Docker | write too long

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Trying to follow the tutorial "Using TensorFlow Serving via Docker": https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/docker

I'm getting the error below:

```
$ docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f Dockerfile.devel .
ERRO[1791] Can't add file /Users/bone/.docker/machine/machines/testD/disk.vmdk to tar: archive/tar: write too long 
Sending build context to Docker daemon 194.3 GB
Error response from daemon: Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: write /.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk: no space left on device
```

Comment: This looks kind of big... `Sending build context to Docker daemon 194.3 GB`. I think your problem is with 'disk spaces'? `no space left on device`

Comment: How much space does tensorflow-serving need?

Comment: don't know what Tensorflow is, I have never use it before. Saw the error message mentioning about your system running out of disk so I thought I'll just let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was running this command on the command line outside the docker machine. Once this command was run inside the docker machine, it worked fine.